# NSZombie in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios, exc-bad-access, nszombie

I have an interesting problem, and I can't seem to find out why it is happening, might be something small that I am overlooking.

I have a UITableView and in my didselectrowatindex path I navigate to a new view, I then navigate to the next view and pop both views to get back to the first and then the app crashes with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS

So I used instruments and NSZombie and found a malloc in didselectrowatindexpath, but I have no idea why

Here is my code:

```
if([workflowswithdirectories count] == 0)
{
    WorkflowViewController *aWorkFlow = [[WorkflowViewController alloc] init];
    MenuObject *obj = [workflownames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    aWorkFlow.heading = obj.name;
    aWorkFlow.workId = obj.workflowid;
    aWorkFlow.siteId = obj.siteid;
    aWorkFlow.item = obj;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aWorkFlow animated:YES];

}
else if([workflownames count] == 0)
{
    WorkflowListViewController *work = [[WorkflowListViewController alloc] init];
    work.siteId = self.siteId;
    MenuObject *obj = [workflowswithdirectories objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    work.menu = obj.next;
    work.heading = obj.name;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:work animated:YES];
}
else
{
    if([indexPath section] == 0)
    {
        WorkflowListViewController *work = [[WorkflowListViewController alloc] init];
        work.siteId = self.siteId;
        MenuObject *obj = [workflowswithdirectories objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        work.menu = obj.next;
        work.heading = obj.name;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:work animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        WorkflowViewController *aWorkFlow = [[WorkflowViewController alloc] init];
        MenuObject *obj = [workflownames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        aWorkFlow.heading = obj.name;
        aWorkFlow.workId = obj.workflowid;
        aWorkFlow.siteId = obj.siteid;
        aWorkFlow.item = obj;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:aWorkFlow animated:YES];  //Malloc is on this line
    }
}  
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

EDIT:

Something I forgot to mention is, in certain cases I push another one of this same class onto the navigationcontroller, but it is only when going to the WorkflowViewController and then to the next viewcontroller and then back twice that the exception is thrown

Comment: What if you made your new ViewController a strong property instead of a method iVar.  That would give you a guarantee that it wouldn't be released too early.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors happen when you try to access an object that has already been released. You should post a code snippet on the methods that you use to pop back to the original view. You mentioned that you are pushing at least one other view. Maybe you're releasing the object in question there?

Comment: Can you show us the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method? Just paste your whole traceback. To know more about the error use malloc_history from terminal.

Comment: @JustinXXVII, it looks like he's using ARC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For memory and efficiency's sake, make all UIViewControllers strong properties (with a backing iVar) to guarantee they stay around long enough for anything useful.